# Custom NumericUpDown Cell Flickering

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm implementing a custom NumericUpDown cell into my dataGridView using this tutorial from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx

It's working good, but the problem is that when Im NOT editing its value, my form/grid start to flick like crazy, and when I click to edit the value it stop.

My form is already "Double Buffered", so I'm not sure what to do anymore.

The code can be find in the link above, but I'm posting both classes I'm using to make it work:

http://pastebin.com/bdhWbgJU
and
http://pastebin.com/FeH3qHEb

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: It seems you are constantly updating its value. But yes, please give us some code.

Comment: Code added, it was too big, so I used pastebin

Comment: _"it was too big"_ -- it's your job as questioner to produce [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. The question must be self-contained, without relying on links to external resources. The code must be small enough to be included in your actual question. If it's not possible to create such a code example for your question, then your question is far too broad in scope for Stack Overflow. Please update your question with an appropriate code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code posted in pastebin seems overly complicated. You might want to try rewriting the control. I created a template for you, and the simplistic version does not seem to have any flicker.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Opulos.Core.UI {

public class DgvNumericUpDownColumn : DataGridViewColumn {

    public int DecimalPlaces { get; set; }

    public DgvNumericUpDownColumn() : base(new NumericUpDownCell()) {
        this.ValueType = typeof(decimal?);
        this.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n0";
    }

    public DgvNumericUpDownColumn(int decimalPlaces) : this() {
        this.DecimalPlaces = decimalPlaces;
        this.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n" + decimalPlaces;
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate {
        get {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set {
            if (!(value is NumericUpDownCell))
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a NumericUpDownCell");

            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}

public class NumericUpDownCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell {

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, Object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle) {
        // required to initialize the editing control:
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
        var nud = (NumericUpDownEditingControl) DataGridView.EditingControl;
        var cc = (DgvNumericUpDownColumn) this.OwningColumn;
        nud.DecimalPlaces = cc.DecimalPlaces;
        Object val = this.Value;
        if (val == null || val == DBNull.Value) {
            nud.Value = (nud.Minimum <= 0 && nud.Maximum >= 0 ? 0 : nud.Minimum);
        }
        else {
            nud.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(val);
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType {
        get {
            return typeof(NumericUpDownEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType {
        get {
            return base.ValueType;
        }
        set {
            base.ValueType = value;
        }
    }

    public override Object DefaultNewRowValue {
        get {
            return DBNull.Value;
        }
    }
}

public class NumericUpDownEditingControl : NumericUpDown, IDataGridViewEditingControl {

    private bool Cancelling = false;

    public NumericUpDownEditingControl() {
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue property.
    public Object EditingControlFormattedValue {
        get {
            // must return a String
            // it doesn't matter if the value is formatted, it will be replaced
            // by the formatting events
            String s = "" + this.Value.ToString();
            return s;
        }

        set {
            decimal val = 0;
            if (value is decimal)
                this.Value = (decimal) value;
            else {
                String s = "" + value;
                if (s.Length > 0) {
                    if (decimal.TryParse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out val))
                        this.Value = val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e) {
        if (!Cancelling) {
            var dgv = this.EditingControlDataGridView;
            var cell = (NumericUpDownCell) dgv.CurrentCell;
            String s = this.Text;
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                cell.Value = DBNull.Value;
            else {
                decimal m = this.Value;
                cell.Value = Math.Round(m, this.DecimalPlaces);
            }
        }

        base.OnLeave(e);
        Cancelling = false;
    }

    private void ProcessValue(Direction transferFocusDirection) {
        var dgv = this.EditingControlDataGridView;
        var cell = (NumericUpDownCell) dgv.CurrentCell;

        if (!Cancelling)
            cell.Value = this.Value;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) {
            Cancelling = true;
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            var dgv = this.EditingControlDataGridView;
            dgv.CancelEdit();
            dgv.EndEdit();
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method. 
    public Object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context) {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method. 
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle) {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        this.ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
        this.BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex property. 
    public int EditingControlRowIndex { get; set; }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey method. 
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey) {
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode) {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
            case Keys.Escape:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit method. 
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll) {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property. 
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView property. 
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView { get; set; }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged property. 
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged { get; set; }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor property. 
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor {
        get {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Sample Usage:

```
public class FormDgvNud : Form {
    DataGridView dgv = null;
    public FormDgvNud() {
        dgv = CreateDataBoundView();
        dgv.EditingControlShowing += dgv_EditingControlShowing;
        Controls.Add(dgv);
    }

    // example on how to apply constraints:
    private void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Control is NumericUpDown) {
            var nud = (NumericUpDown) e.Control;
            nud.Minimum = -10000m;
            nud.Maximum = 10000m;
        }
    }

    private static DataGridView CreateDataBoundView() {
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(double));

        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DgvNumericUpDownColumn(2) { DataPropertyName = "Column1", HeaderText = "NUD1" });
        dgv.DataSource = table;
        return dgv;
    }

    private static DataGridView CreateUnboundView() {
        var dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DgvNumericUpDownColumn(2) { DataPropertyName = "Column1", HeaderText = "NUD1" });
        dgv.Rows.Add();
        return dgv;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a way to add some parameters to that cell? For example, a way to set the minimum, maximum, increment value to the numericUpDown that will be there?

Comment: Yes. In the `NumericUpDownColumn` class, add the properties you want to support (e.g. `MinValue`, `MaxValue`, `ThousandsSeparator`, etc.). Then in the `NumericUpDownCell` `InitializeEditingControl(...)` method, uncomment the `//NumericUpDownColumn cc = ...` line, and then assign the properties to `ctl`, e.g. `ctl.MinValue = cc.MinValue`.

Comment: What about if I want different properties for each Cell? Is that possible? I'm trying to get the specific cell, but no sucess

Comment: In that case, you can either listen for the `dgv.CellBeginEdit` or subclass `DataGridView` and override the `OnCellBeginEdit` method. Then in that code, set the properties / constraints for the `NumericUpDownColumn` for that particular cell. You will need to maintain some dictionary that stores the constraints. Maybe the constraints are based on some primary key in your table or maybe they are based on the row-index.

Comment: So when the begin-edit happens, you look-up the constraints based on however your constraints are stored, and then set the `NumericUpDownColumn`'s properties (e.g. `MinValue`, `MaxValue`) with those values.

Comment: I made like this: http://pastebin.com/eLfW3kC1 , it is setting the values correctly, but when I click to edit a second cell it try to use the first cell values, so if I set the minimum on cell [0,4] to 100, and in the cell [1,4] to 10, when I change the second cell value to < 100 it crashs, cuz it try to use the minimum of the first cell I edited, the cell[0,4]

Comment: It looks wrong setting the constraints only if the value is initially null. They should always be set. The way to go is probably to first set `ctl.MinValue = decimal.MinValue; ctl.MaxValue = decimal.MaxValue;`, then set `ctl.Value = ...;` and then finally set the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` contraints to the restricted range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87833/discussion-between-kyore-and-loathing).

Comment: It seems that `ProcessValue` method in `NumericUpDownEditingControl` and so `Direction` enum are not required (not used anywhere, can be removed from the code) and more important: inside `InitializeEditingControl` method, you have to set ctl.Value as: `ctl.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(trueValue);` instead of `(decimal)trueValue;` as it gives an error (cant convert object to decimal)!