# C# DataGridView - Detect Cell value Change

Tags: c#, datagridview

I finally found a custom NumericUpDownCell that works for me. (Link: [custom NumericUpDownCell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162779/2803565), created by Loathing.) All is well and good.

But now a new problem arises: If I use the up arrow to increase the amount of products to buy, I want to increase the value of another column (the price-cell) as well immediately (not after leaving the cell). How can I create a listener that reacts when the amount-cell-value is changed?

I tried using the CellValueChanged-event on the DataGridView. But that reacted strangely: first when I started the application (I'm guessing the DataGridView was created and it reacted to that.) Secondly it reacted first after I had deselected the cell in which I was increasing the value.

I want it to react immediately when I click on the up-arrow. I thought maybe there was a way to mod Loathing's code to add a listener for this? But I'm not competent enough to do that myself. Unless there's a built-in way to do it, which I haven't found yet?

Comment: whats the current code you use for it? the link you provided is itself a question, are you using exactly the answer given to that question?

Comment: Yes, I am using the code in the answer to the question in the link. (Created by Loathing.)

Comment: We.need code, this is futile attempting to debug without seeing anything at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `EditingControlShowing` event of the DataGridView and register an event handler for `ValueChanged` event of `EditingControl` as in following code:

```
NumericUpDownEditingControl lastCtl = null;
EventHandler handler = null;

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var ctl = e.Control as NumericUpDownEditingControl;
    if (ctl != null) //&& ctl != lastCtl
    {
        if (handler == null) handler = new EventHandler(myUpDownCtl_ValueChanged); //save a handler has better performance
        //Event => ValueChanged: just fires for Up/Dn btn or when press enter, TextChanged: also fired during user typing
        if (lastCtl != null) lastCtl.ValueChanged -= handler; //ensure we remove our handler. 
        lastCtl = ctl;
        lastCtl.ValueChanged += handler; //we can use myUpDownCtl_ValueChanged directly instead of that handler var
        //handler(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

void myUpDownCtl_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("New value: " + lastCtl.Value.ToString());
    //Grid1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value = lastCtl.Value * 10; //sample to change other columns based on this value
}
```

Note: the `ValueChanged` event fires only for Up/Down buttons or when user type some number and press Enter. if you want to update also while user types inside the Numeric TextBox, then use `TextChanged` instead!

Also note to the comment i posted on that answer provided by Loathing about `InitializeEditingControl` method.

Update:

this is the whole code to test:

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    NumericUpDownEditingControl lastCtl = null;
    EventHandler handler = null;

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctl = e.Control as NumericUpDownEditingControl;
        if (ctl != null) //&& ctl != lastCtl
        {
            if (handler == null) handler = new EventHandler(myUpDownCtl_ValueChanged); //save a handler has better performance
            //Event => ValueChanged: just fires for Up/Dn btn or when press enter, TextChanged: also fired during user typing
            if (lastCtl != null) lastCtl.ValueChanged -= handler; //ensure we remove our handler. 
            lastCtl = ctl;
            lastCtl.ValueChanged += handler; //we can use myUpDownCtl_ValueChanged directly instead of that handler var
            //handler(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    void myUpDownCtl_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("New value: " + lastCtl.Value.ToString());
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = lastCtl.Value * 10; //sample to change other columns based on this value
    }

} //end Form


//****************************************************************


public class NumericUpDownColumn : DataGridViewColumn {

    public NumericUpDownColumn() : base(new NumericUpDownCell()) {
        this.ValueType = typeof(decimal?);
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate {
        get {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set {
            if (!(value is NumericUpDownCell))
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a NumericUpDownCell");

            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}

public class NumericUpDownCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell {

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, Object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle) {
        // required to initialize the editing control:
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
        var ctl = (NumericUpDownEditingControl) DataGridView.EditingControl;
        //NumericUpDownColumn cc = (NumericUpDownColumn) this.OwningColumn;
        if (this.Value == null || this.Value == DBNull.Value) {
            ctl.Value = (ctl.Minimum <= 0 && ctl.Maximum >= 0 ? 0 : ctl.Minimum);
        }
        else {
            Object trueValue = this.Value;
            ctl.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(trueValue); //(decimal)trueValue; 
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType {
        get {
            return typeof(NumericUpDownEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType {
        get {
            return base.ValueType;
        }
        set {
            base.ValueType = value;
        }
    }

    public override Object DefaultNewRowValue {
        get {
            return DBNull.Value;
        }
    }
}

[ToolboxItem(false)] //don't show this as a new control in toolbox
public class NumericUpDownEditingControl : NumericUpDown, IDataGridViewEditingControl {

    private bool Cancelling = false;

    public NumericUpDownEditingControl() {
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue property.
    public Object EditingControlFormattedValue {
        get {
            // must return a String
            // it doesn't matter if the value is formatted, it will be replaced
            // by the formatting events
            String s = "" + this.Value.ToString();
            return s;
        }

        set {
            decimal val = 0;
            if (value is decimal)
                this.Value = (decimal) value;
            else {
                String s = "" + value;
                if (s.Length > 0) {
                    if (decimal.TryParse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out val))
                        this.Value = val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e) {
        if (!Cancelling) {
            var dgv = this.EditingControlDataGridView;
            var cell = (NumericUpDownCell) dgv.CurrentCell;
            cell.Value = this.Value;
        }

        base.OnLeave(e);
        Cancelling = false;
    }


    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) {
            Cancelling = true;
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            var dgv = this.EditingControlDataGridView;
            dgv.CancelEdit();
            dgv.EndEdit();
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    // Implements the  IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method. 
    public Object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context) {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method. 
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle) {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        this.ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
        this.BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex property. 
    public int EditingControlRowIndex { get; set; }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey method. 
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey) {
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode) {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
            case Keys.Escape:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit method. 
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll) {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property. 
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView property. 
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView { get; set; }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged property. 
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged { get; set; }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor property. 
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor {
        get {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. =)

Comment: Actually a new issue arose: I added the code and played around with the dataTables a bit. Selecting one row and increasing/decreasing the value works like a charm. But if I select Row 1, change value, then select Row 2 and attempt to change the value - the application crashes; giving me a 'NullReferenceException'. Is there some way to add a try/ catch to the code in order to suppress this Exception?

Comment: i tested it and it works well, can you give your full code here?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem comes from something I'm doing after implementing your code. Here's what I'm trying to do: Listen to cell value change. Check the new value. Add X Product-objects to a list (ShoppingCart), where X is the new value in the changed cell. Then I need to update the ShoppingCart-Table with the new values. (Ie: Amount went up by one, Price went up by x2) The way I have been doing the update is: Remove everything from the table, loop through ShoppingCart (list), add each item to the ShoppingCart-Table. <- I think this might be the issue.

Comment: i can't understand your explanation totally, put some breakpoints inside your code and debug it to find where the issue raises

Comment: After an hour of troubelshooting I stumbled upon something. It seems that this line is the cause of the NullReferenceException: `int newValue = Convert.ToInt32(lastCtl.Value);`

I tried checking `if (lastCtl.Value!=null)` - but Visual Studio tells me that it will always be true, since a decimal can never have a null value.

Comment: the `lastCtl` is a control and can itself be null (check it at debug time to ensure whats the problem). you can also try to get value of numeric up-down column directly from GridView this way: `string vStr = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(); int v = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vStr) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(vStr));` where `v` will be its numeric value. (here i assume NumericUpDown is at column 2 as wrote Cells[2])

Comment: That solved it! Only "do stuff" `if (lastCtl!=null)`, otherwise run the risk of getting a NullReferenceException. Thank you for all the help. Let's hope I don't run into more issues now. =)